# How to create a custom webhook for clickfunnels in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, webhooks

I need to create a custom endpoint in WordPress to work with webhooks in Clickfunnels.

The Clickfunnels documentation is not clear on this. According to the clickfunnels documentation, I have to add in my endpoint:

- create a test endpoint in <your-domain/funnel_webhooks/test>

And you must include the headers below.

- Content type as application / json
- X-Clickfunnels-Webhook-Delivery-Id as MD5 of the URL and payload.
- The payload (HTTP message body) shall be a JSON object with a "time"
  key and the current time value in UTC as follows: { "time":
  "YYYYY-MM-DD HH: MM: SS UTC"}

Actually this is my code, I have successfully created the endpoint, but unfortunately Clickfunnels does not recognize it. I think that the problem may be in the headers that I add...

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'funnel-webhooks', '/test',
        array(
            'methods' => 'GET', 
            'callback' => 'ffalcon_funnel_webhooks'
        )
    );
});
function ffalcon_funnel_webhooks(){

    // Set the arguments based on our get parameters
    $today = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s e');
    $data = array();
    $data['time'] = $today;
  $Clickfunnels_Webhook_Delivery_Id = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . $today;

    $response = new WP_REST_Response(json_encode($data), 200);
  $response->header( 'X-Clickfunnels-Webhook-Delivery-Id', md5($Clickfunnels_Webhook_Delivery_Id) ); 
  $response->set_data(json_encode($data));
  return $response;
    
}
```

This is the url of my custom endpoint: https://test.umanyx.com/wp-json/funnel-webhooks/test

Does anyone have experience, creating custom endpoints in WordPress to work with Clickfunnels webhooks.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you sending the MD5 hash of the current date - when the documentation you quoted explicitly said, _"as MD5 of the URL and payload"_?

Comment: Thank you for your response @CBroe 
I don't really understand what the documentation refers to in this sentence.
X-Clickfunnels-Webhook-Delivery-Id as MD5 of the URL and payload.
I do not know what I have to put as content of the this headers X-Clickfunnels-Webhook-Delivery-Id

Any idea would be of great help to me

Comment: Well the URL would probably be that of your endpoint itself, and the payload (which you are currently not actually sending, btw.) is clearly explained in the next point. So unless there's any more specific instructions, you are likely just supposed to concatenate both together, and then calculate the MD5 of that.

Comment: @Broe I have changed my code according to your suggestion... 

Unfortunately Clickfunnels still does not recognize it successfully.

This is the url of my endpoint: https://test.umanyx.com/wp-json/funnel-webhooks/test

Comment: Your payload is still not JSON. Plus you are not actually sending it.

Comment: On this page, is the documentation provided by clickfunnels

https://help.clickfunnels.com/hc/es/articles/360039820293-Webhooks-en-ClickFunnels

And this is the url of my endpoint 

https://test.umanyx.com/wp-json/funnel-webhooks/test

Comment: Your `$today` values is likely not even in the correct format yet (have you verified what format you are getting with that, on your system?), should probably use `gmdate` instead. And your payload needs to be `json_encode($data)`. And you need to actually send the payload, not _just_ the header.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please can you tell me how I can add the payload to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, passing it as parameter to the WP_REST_Response constructor should already do that, I overlooked you had that in there.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I was able to fix it. I leave the code that worked for me in case it helps anyone.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'funnel-webhooks', '/test',
        array(
            'methods' => 'POST', 
            'callback' => 'ffalcon_funnel_webhooks_test'
        )
    );
    register_rest_route( 'funnel-webhooks', '/real',
        array(
            'methods' => 'POST', 
            'callback' => 'ffalcon_funnel_webhooks_real'
        )
    );
});
function ffalcon_funnel_webhooks_test(){

    $today = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s e');
    $data = array();
    $data['time'] = $today;
    $Clickfunnels_Webhook_Delivery_Id = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . $today;

    $response = new WP_REST_Response(json_encode($data), 200);
    $response->header( 'X-Clickfunnels-Webhook-Delivery-Id', md5($Clickfunnels_Webhook_Delivery_Id) ); 
  
  return $response;
    
}
```